# Unable to 'tidy' html file

Tags: html, selenium

I am trying to use `tidy` to create a prettyfied html code. I am using it like follows:

```
tidy -i -utf8 output/page_1530597755.html -b -o test.html
```

but no output file is generated! Instead a lot of warnings and an error is shown.

I am not interested in errors or warning. I just want the original html file to be prettyfied. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better tool to do that which is capable of ignoring not-so-nice html? Just to be sure: The html is saved from an actual html page using selenium...

Comment: search `soup.prettify()` in the following link, which might be helpful to u https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

To create a prettyfied html code you can use *Python* and **`prettify()`** method from [**Beautiful Soup**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  url = 'https://www.flybondi.com/search/dates?adults=1&children=0%C2%A4cy=ARS&fromCityCode=COR&infants=0&toCityCode=EPA'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
  print(soup.prettify())
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="#FDBE15" name="theme-color"/>
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
    <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>
    <meta content="1.12.0" property="app:version"/>
    <meta content="https://www.flybondi.com" property="og:url"/>
    <meta content="Flybondi.com | La libertad de volar" property="og:title"/>
    <meta content="La libertad de volar" property="og:description"/>
    <meta content="https://scdn.flybondi.com/images/og-image.jpg" property="og:image"/>
    <meta content="731377167047101" property="fb:app_id"/>
    <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    <link href="/assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180"/>
    <link href="/assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
    <link href="/assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
    <link color="#fdbe15" href="/assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" rel="mask-icon"/>
    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=GTM-TCRQWWG&amp;t=gtm1&amp;cid=309963460.1530600855" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/dd5780a18ee53434fc14a0ad1/4f603909908292a20e864d6ca.js">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/113559949307295?v=2.8.18&amp;r=stable">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1363878953707751?v=2.8.18&amp;r=stable">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0072/3397.js?425166" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="//static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-587087.js?sv=5" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/iZAEUq48sbC9QFfUcVjkwDST9WObGhBJ/analytics.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-5RHG3K">
    </script>
    <script data-cfasync="false">
     !function(e,t,a,n,g){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var m=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],r=t.createElement(a);r.async=!0,r.src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-5RHG3K",m.parentNode.insertBefore(r,m)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer")
    </script>
    <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
     !function(){var n=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!n.initialize)if(n.invoked)window.console&amp;&amp;console.error&amp;&amp;console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{n.invoked=!0,n.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","debug","page","once","off","on"],n.factory=function(e){return function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return t.unshift(e),n.push(t),n}};for(var t=0;t&lt;n.methods.length;t++){var e=n.methods[t];n[e]=n.factory(e)}n.load=function(t){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)},n.SNIPPET_VERSION="4.0.0",n.load("iZAEUq48sbC9QFfUcVjkwDST9WObGhBJ")}}()
    </script>
    <title>
     Flybondi.com | La libertad de volar
    </title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.02379d06.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script async="" charset="utf-8" src="/static/js/0.904e6ddf.chunk.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
     .animation-loading-1{background:url("/assets/images/loading/loading-1.gif") no-repeat 50%;background-size:cover}.animation-loading-2{background:url("/assets/images/loading/loading-2.gif") no-repeat 50%;background-size:cover}.animation-loading-3{background:url("/assets/images/loading/loading-3.gif") no-repeat 50%;background-size:cover}.animation-loading-4{background:url("/assets/images/loading/loading-4.gif") no-repeat 50%;background-size:cover}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     .CalendarMonth--vertical-scrollable .calendar-day .day{font-size:1rem}.calendar-day .fare-price{font-size:.7rem;margin-top:-3px}.calendar-day .fare-price:empty{margin-top:.75rem}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     .arrow-right{width:0;height:0;border-top:10px solid transparent;border-bottom:10px solid transparent;border-left:15px solid #4f4c4d}.DayPicker{position:relative;text-align:left}.DayPicker--vertical-scrollable{height:100%}.DayPicker__week-headers{position:relative}.DayPicker--vertical-scrollable .DayPicker__week-header{display:table-row;left:0;margin-left:0;text-align:center;top:0;width:100%}.DayPicker__week-header{background-color:#fff;color:#bdbbbc;padding:0 13px;position:absolute;text-align:left;text-transform:uppercase;top:62px;z-index:2}.DayPicker__week-header ul{list-style:none;margin:1px 0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0}.DayPicker__week-header li{display:inline-block;text-align:center}.DayPicker__focus-region{outline:none}.DayPicker--vertical-scrollable .transition-container--vertical{bottom:0;height:100%;left:0;overflow-y:scroll;padding-top:20px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:100%}.transition-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden;border-radius:3px}.transition-container--horizontal{-webkit-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:height .2s ease-in-out;transition:height .2s ease-in-out}.CalendarMonthGrid--vertical-scrollable{margin:0 auto;overflow-y:scroll}.CalendarMonthGrid{z-index:0;text-align:left}.CalendarMonth{text-align:center;padding:0 13px;vertical-align:top;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.CalendarMonth--vertical-scrollable .CalendarMonth__caption{padding:5px 0}.CalendarMonth--horizontal:first-of-type,.CalendarMonth--vertical:first-of-type{position:absolute;z-index:-1;opacity:0;pointer-events:none}.CalendarMonth--horizontal{display:inline-block;min-height:100%}.CalendarMonth__caption{background-color:#e9e8e8;color:#4f4c4d;caption-side:top;font-size:.875rem;margin-bottom:2px;margin-top:7px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase}.CalendarMonth--horizontal .CalendarMonth__caption{padding:15px 0 35px}.CalendarMonth table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}.CalendarMonthGrid--animating{-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;transition:-webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:transform .2s ease-in-out;transition:transform .2s ease-in-out;transition:transform .2s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;z-index:1}.CalendarDay{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;color:#565a5c;cursor:pointer;padding:0}.CalendarDay--hovered{background:#f4f4f4;color:inherit}.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--selected-end.CalendarDay--blocked.CalendarDay--hovered,.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--selected-start.CalendarDay--blocked.CalendarDay--hovered{background-color:#fdbe15!important}.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range.CalendarDay--hovered,.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--blocked.CalendarDay--hovered{background-color:#fff!important}.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range .CalendarDay__button,.CalendarDay.CalendarDay--blocked .CalendarDay__button{cursor:auto}.CalendarDay--selected,.CalendarDay--selected-end,.CalendarDay--selected-span,.CalendarDay--selected-start{background:#fdbe15;color:#fff}.CalendarDay--selected-start{border-bottom-left-radius:30px;border-top-left-radius:30px}.CalendarDay--selected-end{border-bottom-right-radius:30px;border-top-right-radius:30px}.CalendarDay--selected-end.CalendarDay--blocked,.CalendarDay--selected-start.CalendarDay--blocked{color:#fff}.CalendarDay--selected-end:active,.CalendarDay--selected-span.CalendarDay--hovered,.CalendarDay--selected-span:active,.CalendarDay--selected-start.CalendarDay--hovered-span,.CalendarDay--selected-start:active,.CalendarDay--selected:active{background:#fdbe15}.CalendarDay--after-hovered-start,.CalendarDay--after-hovered-start:active,.CalendarDay--hovered-span,.CalendarDay--hovered-span:active{background:#e9e8e8}.CalendarDay__button{position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;text-align:center;background:none;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;color:inherit;font:inherit;font-size:1.5rem;line-height:normal;overflow:visible;cursor:pointer;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.CalendarDay__button:active{outline:0}.CalendarDay--blocked{color:#bdbbbc;cursor:not-allowed}.CalendarDay--blocked:active{background:#fff}.DayPickerNavigation__next,.DayPickerNavigation__prev{cursor:pointer;line-height:.78;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.DayPickerNavigation__next--default,.DayPickerNavigation__prev--default{border:1px solid #dce0e0;background-color:#fff;color:#e9e8e8}.DayPickerNavigation__next--default:focus,.DayPickerNavigation__next--default:hover,.DayPickerNavigation__prev--default:focus,.DayPickerNavigation__prev--default:hover{border:1px solid #bdbbbc;outline:0}.DayPickerNavigation__next--default:active,.DayPickerNavigation__prev--default:active{background:#e9e8e8;outline:0}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical{background:#fff;bottom:0;left:0;height:52px;width:100%;z-index:2}.DayPicker--horizontal.DayPicker--portal{-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical .DayPickerNavigation__next--default,.DayPickerNavigation--vertical .DayPickerNavigation__prev--default{border:none;font-size:2.5em;text-align:center}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical .DayPickerNavigation__next--default svg,.DayPickerNavigation--vertical .DayPickerNavigation__prev--default svg{height:55px;width:80px;fill:#4f4c4d}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable{position:relative}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable .DayPickerNavigation__next{width:100%}.DayPickerNavigation.DayPickerNavigation--vertical.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable button{position:relative;-webkit-transition:.2s ease-out;-o-transition:.2s ease-out;transition:.2s ease-out}.DayPickerNavigation.DayPickerNavigation--vertical.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable button:active,.DayPickerNavigation.DayPickerNavigation--vertical.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable button:hover{-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);opacity:.8}.DayPicker--horizontal{margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.DayPicker--horizontal .DayPicker__week-headers{margin-left:9px}.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal{position:relative}.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__next,.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__prev{border-radius:3px;padding:6px 9px;top:18px;z-index:2;position:absolute}.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__prev{left:22px}.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__next{right:22px}.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__next--default svg,.DayPickerNavigation--horizontal .DayPickerNavigation__prev--default svg{height:19px;width:19px;fill:#4f4c4d}@media screen and (min-width:30em){.CalendarDay--selected-start{border-bottom-left-radius:100px;border-top-left-radius:100px}.CalendarDay--selected-end{border-bottom-right-radius:100px;border-top-right-radius:100px}.CalendarMonth__caption{background-color:#fff;font-size:1.25rem}.DayPicker__week-header li{text-transform:capitalize}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable{text-align:center}.DayPickerNavigation--vertical-scrollable .DayPickerNavigation__next{width:50%}}@media screen and (min-width:30em) and (max-width:60em){.CalendarDay__button{font-size:1.6rem}.DayPicker{margin:0 auto}}@media screen and (min-width:60em){.CalendarDay__button{font-size:1.7rem}}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     .button-selector{width:36px;padding:7px}.border-left-radius{border-bottom-left-radius:20px;border-bottom-right-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:20px;border-top-right-radius:0}.border-right-radius{border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:20px;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:20px}.selector{display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px 8px;width:16px}.ReactModal__Content{-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;transition:-webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:transform .4s ease-in-out;transition:transform .4s ease-in-out;transition:transform .4s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .4s ease-in-out;-webkit-transform:translateY(500px);-ms-transform:translateY(500px);transform:translateY(500px)}.ReactModal__Content--after-open{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);-ms-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}.ReactModal__Content--before-close{-webkit-transform:translateY(500px);-ms-transform:translateY(500px);transform:translateY(500px)}.ReactModal__Overlay{opacity:0;z-index:2147483647}.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open{opacity:1;-webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out}.ReactModal__Overlay--before-close{opacity:0}.ReactModal__Body--open{overflow:hidden}.ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open{max-height:calc(100% - 100px)}.notification-bar{position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-100%;width:100%;padding:1.5rem 1rem;margin:0;color:#fafafa;background:#3f4853;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(10,10,11,.125) 0 0 1px 1px;box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px rgba(10,10,11,.125);cursor:default;-webkit-transition:.5s cubic-bezier(.89,.01,.5,1.1);-o-transition:.5s cubic-bezier(.89,.01,.5,1.1);transition:.5s cubic-bezier(.89,.01,.5,1.1);-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);opacity:.9;line-height:1.38;text-align:left}.notification-bar-active{left:0;bottom:0}.notification-bar-message{font-size:14px;text-transform:lowercase}.notification-bar:first-letter{text-transform:uppercase}.notification-bar-action{position:absolute;right:1rem;font-weight:900}@media screen and (min-width:30em){.notification-bar{bottom:auto;left:auto;right:-100%;top:1rem;width:56%}.notification-bar-active{right:2rem;top:1rem}.notification-bar-message{font-size:1rem;margin-right:1.75rem}}@media screen and (min-width:30em) and (max-width:60em){.notification-bar{width:60%}}@media screen and (min-width:60em){.notification-bar{width:35%}}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     .header-b{border-left:1px solid #e7e7e7}.shadow-h{-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px 0 hsla(0,0%,9%,.1);box-shadow:0 0 4px 0 hsla(0,0%,9%,.1)}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
     .icon-cross{background:url("/assets/images/icon-cross.svg") no-repeat 50%;height:12px;width:12px}
    </style>
    <script src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/855821915/?random=1530600855485&amp;cv=9&amp;fst=1530600855485&amp;num=1&amp;guid=ON&amp;resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=738&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_tz=330&amp;u_java=false&amp;u_nplug=3&amp;u_nmime=4&amp;gtm=G6c&amp;sendb=1&amp;frm=0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flybondi.com%2Fsearch%2Fdates%3Fadults%3D1%26children%3D0%25C2%25A4cy%3DARS%26fromCityCode%3DCOR%26infants%3D0%26toCityCode%3DEPA&amp;tiba=Flybondi.com%20%7C%20La%20libertad%20de%20volar&amp;async=1&amp;rfmt=3&amp;fmt=4">
    </script>
    <script async="" src="https://script.hotjar.com/modules-e3237c54355663e59832fa7359f942ed.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
     iframe#_hjRemoteVarsFrame {display: none !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; opacity: 0 !important; pointer-events: none !important;}
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <noscript>
     You need to enable javascript in order to buy tickets in Flybondi.com
    </noscript>
    <div id="root">
     <div>
      <div style="opacity: 1;">
       <div class="flybondi-app">
        <header class="bg-white h3 shadow-h w-100 z-5">
         <div class="fl pointer pointer:hover tc w-25">
      <a class="dib-l h2 w-logo w-logo-m w-logo-l" href="/">
       <img alt="Flybondi.com" class="bn dn-l pa2 w2" src="/assets/images/logo-small.svg"/>
       <img alt="Flybondi.com" class="bn dn db-l mt3" src="/assets/images/logo.svg"/>
      </a>
         </div>
         <div class="fb-link h-100 header-b f5 fl pa1 pl3 pointer pointer:hover pr3 w-40">
      <a class="color-inherit no-underline">
       <p class="f7 font-l-semibold grey-50 mb1 tracked ttu">
        Vuelo
       </p>
       <div class="dib">
        <span class="ma0">
         Córdoba
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="dib w-50">
        <span class="grey-50 mr2 ml2 ttu">
         &gt;
        </span>
        <span>
         Buenos Aires
        </span>
       </div>
      </a>
         </div>
         <div class="fb-link h-100 header-b f5 fl pa1 pl3 pointer pointer:hover pr3 w-30">
      <p class="f7 font-l-semibold grey-50 mb1 tracked ttu">
       Pasajeros
      </p>
      <p class="ma0 truncate">
       1 Adulto
      </p>
         </div>
        </header>
        <section class="h-100 tc-ns" style="max-height: 481px;">
         <div class="h3-4 ph4-m ph5-l pa3 pb4-ns tc tl-ns">
      <h2 class="f3 font-p-semibold grey-100 mb0 ml4-l">
       Elegí fecha de ida y de vuelta
      </h2>
         </div>
         <div aria-label="Calendar" class="DayPicker DayPicker--horizontal" role="application" style="width: 884px;">
      <div>
       <div aria-hidden="true" class="DayPicker__week-headers" role="presentation">
        <div class="DayPicker__week-header" style="left: 0px;">
         <ul>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            domingo
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            lunes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            martes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            miércoles
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            jueves
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            viernes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            sábado
           </small>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="DayPicker__week-header" style="left: 433px;">
         <ul>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            domingo
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            lunes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            martes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            miércoles
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            jueves
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            viernes
           </small>
          </li>
          <li style="width: 58px;">
           <small>
            sábado
           </small>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="DayPicker__focus-region" role="region" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="DayPickerNavigation DayPickerNavigation--horizontal">
         <button aria-label="Move backward to switch to the previous month" class="DayPickerNavigation__prev DayPickerNavigation__prev--default" type="button">
          <svg viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M336.2 274.5l-210.1 210h805.4c13 0 23 10 23 23s-10 23-23 23H126.1l210.1 210.1c11 11 11 21 0 32-5 5-10 7-16 7s-11-2-16-7l-249.1-249c-11-11-11-21 0-32l249.1-249.1c21-21.1 53 10.9 32 32z">
           </path>
          </svg>
         </button>
         <button aria-label="Move forward to switch to the next month" class="DayPickerNavigation__next DayPickerNavigation__next--default" type="button">
          <svg viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M694.4 242.4l249.1 249.1c11 11 11 21 0 32L694.4 772.7c-5 5-10 7-16 7s-11-2-16-7c-11-11-11-21 0-32l210.1-210.1H67.1c-13 0-23-10-23-23s10-23 23-23h805.4L662.4 274.5c-21-21.1 11-53.1 32-32.1z">
           </path>
          </svg>
         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="transition-container transition-container--horizontal" style="width: 884px; height: 391px;">
         <div class="CalendarMonthGrid CalendarMonthGrid--horizontal" style="transform: translateX(0px); width: 1732px;">
          <div class="CalendarMonth CalendarMonth--horizontal" data-visible="false">
           <div class="CalendarMonth__caption js-CalendarMonth__caption" id="CalendarMonth__caption">
            <strong>
             junio 2018
            </strong>
           </div>
           <table role="presentation">
            <tbody class="js-CalendarMonth__grid">
             <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose viernes, 1 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              1
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose sábado, 2 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              2
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose domingo, 3 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              3
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose lunes, 4 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              4
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose martes, 5 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              5
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose miércoles, 6 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              6
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose jueves, 7 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              7
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose viernes, 8 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              8
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose sábado, 9 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              9
             </div>
             <div class="grey-75 font-p fare-price">
             </div>
            </div>
           </button>
          </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
          <td class="CalendarDay CalendarDay--blocked CalendarDay--blocked-calendar CalendarDay--blocked-out-of-range" style="width: 58px; height: 57px;">
           <button aria-label="Choose domingo, 10 de junio de 2018 as your check-in date. It's available." class="CalendarDay__button" tabindex="-1" type="button">
            <div class="calendar-day">
             <div class="day">
              10
             </div>
  ```